# Weird Scanner class error in for loop

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

the part of my code:

```
public static String[] getNames(int players) {

    System.out.println("What are the names of the players?");

    String[] playerNames = new String[players + 1];
    playerNames[0] = "Dealer";
    for (int i = 1; i < players + 1; i++) {

      playerNames[i] = input.next(); 
    }
    return playerNames;
  }
```

It compiles fine but the problem is when you run it:

```
How many people are playing?
1
What are the names of the players?
Johny
Bob
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextBoolean(Scanner.java:1782)
    at BlackJack.playTurn(BlackJack.java:17)
    at BlackJack.everyoneGo(BlackJack.java:36)
    at BlackJack.main(BlackJack.java:112)
```

another part of the code asks the how many people are playing thing and stores the number entered (1 in this case) as the integer players. Therefore [players +1] in the for loop should equal 2 so the for loop should only run once if you have 1 player, first time the check executes 1 < 2 and second time 2 !< 2 so it shouldn't run but it does for some reason, I shouldn't have been able to enter a second name. Anyways immediately after you enter the second name (or third if you said 2 people etc.) you get the exception and error thing.

I also tried putting system.out.println("test1"); right before and test2 right after the line playerNames[i] = input.next(); to see what happens.

this is the result:

```
How many people are playing?
1
What are the names of the players?
test1
johnny
test2
bob
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextBoolean(Scanner.java:1782)
    at BlackJack.playTurn(BlackJack.java:17)
    at BlackJack.everyoneGo(BlackJack.java:36)
    at BlackJack.main(BlackJack.java:112)
```

as you can see it also didn't print test1 a second time which was at the beginning of the for loop (before it should have asked for the second name) which is really weird.

Any ideas/solutions?

Thanks

Comment: `Scanner.nextBoolean` is your error at `BlackJack.playTurn` line `17`. Nothing to do with the code you have posted at all - as this method is called from `everyoneGo` and called from `main` - you have posted the wrong code. You are trying to parse something that isn't a `boolean` with `nextBoolean`.

Comment: **TL;DR: read your error and post the _relevant_ code.**

Comment: "*Any ideas/solutions?*" Yup, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.